# PnP modern search: syntax to use a page property in query

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, spfx, modern-experience, pnp

Wondering if you can use a **page property** rather than a managed property to filter search results in modern search web parts. Normally I'd use managed properties but either due to a bug or a limitation, managed properties aren't available in group connected team sites - in any of the search based web parts.

So I can filter a highlighted content web part using a page property based on for instance a choice column (eg "Category"), but not a managed property mapped to the crawled property for that column.

I'd like to be able to use a modern search web part with a filter - something like this:

```
Path:https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/SitePages {Page.Category=Advanced tips}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can use the page property to filter the search results within modern search web part.

> The value of a field on the page from where the query was issued. For example, if the page from where the query was issued contained a site column named "ContentOwner," specifying {Page.ContentOwner} would allow you to query for the value of "ContentOwner."
>
> FieldName is the internal name of the field. When used with taxonomy columns, use `{Page.<FieldName>.Label}` or `{Page.<FieldName>.TermID}`

**Source**: [Custom query variables](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/v3/search-parts/search-results/#custom-query-variables)

---

Also, if you are using two or more words together in value, separated by spaces; the words must be enclosed in double quotation marks, like: `"Advanced tips"`.

You can get the exact internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work using. Path: https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/SitePages {Page.Category_x002f_tag="field value"} or any variation replacing = sign with colon, space etc. Always pulls same 10 results when there are 15 or so items in the library.